# Find all sequences that has $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ converges, where $a_i = \sum_{k=i+1}^\infty a_k^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find all sequences that has $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ converges, where $a_i = \sum_{k=i+1}^\infty a_k^2$.

My intuition is that the only sequence of this form is the zero sequence.

Here's what I have so far:
$a_n - a_{n+1} = a_{n+1}^2 \implies a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n + \frac{1}{4}}  - \frac{1}{2}$, but it doesn't seem to lead me anywhere.

Another line of thought is that if $a_i = 0$ for some $i$, it means that $\sum_{k=i+1}^\infty a_k^2=0$, which means that $a_k = 0$ for $k > i$. This will also mean $a_{i-1} = 0, a_{i-2} = 0, \ldots$, making the whole sequence the zero sequence.

It means that $a_i >0 $ for all $i$, yet $\lim a_i = 0$.

The last line I've tried is $a_1 = a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2 + \ldots, a_2 = a_3^2 + a_4^2 + \ldots$, so  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i =  a_2^2 + a_3^2 + a_4^2 + \ldots + a_3^2 + a_4^2 + \ldots = a_2^2 + 2a_3^2 + 3a_4^2 = \sum_{i=2}^\infty (i-1)a_i^2$, which implies a stronger condition of having $ia_i^2 \to 0$. I'm hoping to get a contradiction but it doesn't seem to work.

Python seems to suggest that $(a_n) \approx \frac{1}{n}$ for large $n$.

Any hints?

Comment: I suspect that $a_i$ must be $0$ for all $i$. I changed the summation to an integral - $f(x)=\int_x^{\infty} f(t)^{2} dt$ and found that $f$ must be $0$.

Comment: Is $a_i\ge 0$ in the hypothesis?

Comment: I suspect too but I can't prove it. Did you use integral test?

Comment: Is the hypothesis that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ converges, or that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2$ converges?

Comment: @Gae.S.No, but it is implied since each $a_i$ is made out of a sum of squares

Comment: @StefanLafon Hypothesis is that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ converges, though I believe it is true that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2$ converges as well since after some point, $a_i < 1$ and $a_i^2 < a_i$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why must $f$ be zero? Isn't $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ a solution?

Comment: It's not clear to me why we should expect $a_i=0$ for all $i$. Why this intuition? It must have to do with $\sum_i \frac 1 i$ converges.

Comment: Doh, sorry :) You're right

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. I wanted to say that $\int f(t)dt$ does not exist if $f(x)=\frac  1 x$.

Comment: my simulation says $a_n=O(\frac 1n)$ for $a_1 = 0.1$ but $a_n = O(n\log n)$ for $a_1 = 1.$ But either way, the sum $\sum_{n=1}a_n$ is a very slowly growing function, so it is hard to tell if it converges or diverges super slowly from simulations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim:** If $a_n > \frac{1}{k}$, then $ a_{n+1} > \frac{1}{k+1}$.

**Proof:** [Verify that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+-+1+%2B+%28+1+%2B+4%2Fk%29%5E.5%29+%2F+2+%3E+1%2F+%28k%2B1%29) for $ k > 0$,

$$  a_{n+1} = \frac{ - 1 + \sqrt{ 1 + 4 a_n } }{2}  > \frac{ - 1 + \sqrt{ 1 +\frac{4}{k} } }{2} > \frac{ 1}{k+1}. $$

**Corollary:** If $ a_1  >  \frac{1}{k} $, then $ \sum a_n  > \sum \frac{1}{k - 1 + n }$ which diverges.
Hence, the only sequence where $ \sum a_n$ converges is the all-0 sequence.

Comment: Right, and the last inequality is true because $\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x}} > 1+\frac{2}{x+1}$, which can be seen by squaring both sides

Comment: Yup, it's simple squaring (and I was lazy to write it all out). The crux (of my proof) is the claim.

Comment: noice this is pimpler

Answer (score 1):

So assume $a_1 > 0$. $\ln a_n = \ln a_{n+1} + \ln(a_{n+1}+1)<\ln a_{n+1} +a_{n+1}$ so $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}<e^{a_{n+1}}.$

Therefore, 
$$a_{n+1} = a_1\prod_{i=1}^n\dfrac{a_{i+1}}{a_i}>a_1e^{-\sum_{i=1}^na_{i+1}}.$$ But this gives a lower bound: 
$$a_{n+1} > a_1 e^{-S}$$ 
if $a_1 > 0$ and their sum converges to a positive number $S>0,$ which is in return a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the zero sequence is the only one. Otherwise $a_n>0$ for all $n$ and $$a_n-a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}^2\implies\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n}=\frac{1}{1+a_{n+1}}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1,$$ now [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}na_n=1$. Thus, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges.